# Check if 2 Pandas data frames have same columns

Tags: dataframe

I want to check whether 2 Pandas data frames have same columns or not.
The columns can be in any order. The column names and the data type of each column should match.

I searched on net. There are two Pandas methods to compare dataframes such as equals & compare. But these functions also match the data.
I am looking for a function which will compare only columns (Names in any order and respective data types)

Following is a small code snippet to test the functionality:

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [14,15], 'a': ['12','14']})

print(df_1.columns.sort_values().equals(df_2.columns.sort_values()))
```

Here, data types are not compared. So the output is "True". But actually the columns are not same because the data types are different.

What is the best way to compare the columns (Names in any order and data types) of 2 data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `dtypes` props as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [14,15], 'a': ['12','14']})
if sorted(list(df_1.columns)) == sorted(list(df_2.columns)):
    print("dataframes have same column names")
    if df_1.dtypes.sort_index().equals(df_2.dtypes.sort_index()):
        print("dataframes have same column types")
    else:
        print("dataframes have different column types")
else:
    print("dataframes have different column names")
```

produces:

```
dataframes have same column names
dataframes have different column types
```

Comment: Thanks DobbyTheElf ! The solution solved my issue.